Blender model that goes upside down when I export it to Unity
This is one of a series of problems I have been having exporting FBX to Unity. I have a Blender model that goes upside down when I export it to Unity.
I can't see anything wrong with my export settings. I made sure that the export settings were the same on all my characters ( y up -z forward, FBX all and FBX unit scale, transforms, bake animation, NLA,[...]) and the blender model was facing the same direction in the 3d Viewport. The orientation was correct in my other characters. The only difference is the animation. I have tried everything that they tell you to do online.



I can't apply transforms because it turns into a disaster. I have custom properties keyframes, it could be related.

The animation doesn't play in the game despite it being in the animator. The weird thing is that the animation does play in the inspector with the right orientation. It has the wrong orientation in the image that you click on to see the inspector.

There is a message in the inspector saying: "Root contains position and rotation curves."
The message in the Inspector in Unity is an informational message. The root bone of my model contains "". This is valuable information that could help diagnose the problem in Blender.
I am aware that unity doesn't have the same axis orientation,I have taken this into consideration.
I know I have used some content related to unity, however I consider the content necessary to diagnose the problem in blender. I believe this issue is something to do with blender and not unity but I can't be certain. I don't know what I should do to find the problem. I would appreciate any useful and constructive information.

Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see What should I do if no one answers my question?

Sorry! Next time I will edit my question. The only reason I posted a new one, was because I completely changed the body and needed a reference not because no one answered my question.

@MagnusHikaru What do you mean, you posted a new one because you needed a reference? If you need one question for reference, open it twice in two different browser tabs... then start editing one of them.
